# Viewing user email and provider used in Passport and Sails.js with EJS

Tags: sails.js, passport.js, ejs

How do I see the used login provider in a page made with EJS, Passport and Sails.js? The idea is being able to see it after logging in with facebook or twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours trying, I've found the answer. I'm using the code generated with [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth). It creates a file called AuthController (in api/controllers folder).

In callback function, is called other named passport.callback, which has a line like this:

```
req.session.authenticated = true;
```

After that line, you can put this other line:

```
req.session.provider = req.params.provider;
```

By putting that line, you can access in EJS the login provider selected by the user like this

```
<div>Logged as <%=req.user.email%> (<%=req.session.provider%>)</div>
```